# Redirecting to static page when HTTP method is not found on Node backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http, redirect

I have a single page app written in AngularJS and NodeJS. On the client side, there are several paths that the user can navigate to:

```
http://jabaridash.com/#!/home
http://jabaridash.com/#!/interests/travel
```

When the user types in a path that does not exist such as `http://jabaridash.com/#!/foo`, AngularJS handles it by rerouting to the `/notFound` path, and then that page redirects the user back to the home page. This is the code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/notFound');
```

This works when the path begins with `#!/anyPath`. However, if I were to type `jabaridash.com/whatever`, Angular does not reroute it. I am not sure if that has to do with the fact that I am using $stateProvider and modules to navigate, or I need to handle that type of path on the backend. I am assuming that I need to handle it on the Node side, because I do have one REST endpoint called `photography` setup on the NodeJS side, which can be accessed via `jabaridash.com/photography` (without `#!`). This endpoint works fine, but any other endpoint that I do not have setup will get a response of:

```
Cannot GET /something
```

This is to be expected, as there is no endpoint there. So essentially, how do i get NodeJS to redirect to my index.html. The way that I am serving the static page follows:

```
/**
 * @description Set up the server
 *
 * @param dir directory to serve the index.html from
 */
function setupServer(dir) {
  server.use(express.static(dir), function(req, res, next) {

    // Allow cross origin from any host
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    next();
  });

  // Set up the photography REST endpoint
  photography_controller(server, dir);
}
```

My photography endpoint is setup as follows:

```
server.get('/photography', function(req, res) {

  var searchPath = '/client/modules/interests/photography/img/thumbnail/';

  // Send the list of files for use on client side
  res.send(fileList(dir + searchPath, searchPath));
});
```

Is there a generic way to tell Node to say..."If the endpoint / HTTP method is not defined for a given path, redirect to a known path?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after your routes definition, do the following:

```
server.get('/photography', function(req, res) {
  //do something
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });
    //
    // error handler
    server.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      //render the page you want to navigate to. In this example, I navigate the user to google
      res.redirect('http://google.com');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet below tells express to redirect to `not-found` when the path start with `/example` but has no specified handler in the router. Other routes that don't start with `/example` will not redirect because they won't be routed into the router in the first place.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// create a router for /example
var router = express.Router()
.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('example home');
})
.post('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About example');
})
/*  catch all middleware for routes starting
    with /example that redirects to /not-found */
.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return res.redirect('/not-found');
});

// attach router
app.use('/example', router);

// create a not-found router handler
app.get('/not-found', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Not found page');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App listening on port 3000'));
```